# Sharepoint 2007 List migration with large size data

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, data-migration

We have a sharepoint 2007 list with attachments and its size is more than 7 GB. We tried to save it as a template [with content] and migrate it to sharepoint 2010 environment. But the template couldn't be saved because of its large size. Could you please provide any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

[I would recommend this tool](http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/), very useful for moving around bits of content.

Comment: Just an fyi, the tool @Dan recommended is not an upgrade tool. Quote from codeplex: "this tool is NOT an upgrade tool. It can only be used to move/copy content within a SharePoint environment, or across multiple SharePoint environments which are at the same version. It cannot be used to move content from SP2007 to SP2010, or SP2010 to SP2013 etc"